# Lottie SplashScreen error in device Android. Ionic Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, lottie

I have a problem with my **LottieSplashScreen**.
I am testing on a **Samsung As10. With Version Android 11** on the smartphone.

StatusBar pink :

[image]

My ionic-cordova and android versions are as follows:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.9 (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.4.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 11.0.0, ios 6.2.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 12 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
   native-run (update available: 1.7.2) : 1.4.1

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/user/NuevosDocs/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v14.19.1 (/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.19.1/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.14.16
   OS                : Linux 5.15
```

and this is my configuration in the **config.xml**. I show the *general and android preferences*.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.xxxxx.xxx" ios-CFBundleVersion="xxx" version="xxx" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>App</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="LottieAnimationLocation" value="www/assets/lottieSplashScreen/hiAnimationLottie.json" />
    <preference name="LottieScaleType" value="CENTER_CROP" />
    <preference name="LottieFullScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="LottieBackgroundColor" value="#5988B5" />
    <preference name="LottieLoopAnimation" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="25" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="32" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#5988B5" />
        <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/iconSplash.png" />
        <preference name="GradlePluginKotlinEnabled" value="true" />
        <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^5.1.0" />
</widget>
```

I have already tried `<preferences="FullScreen" value="true" />` or different **Lottie settings** like 100% high or **config.xml workarounds to remove the StatusBar** but nothing has worked.

Has anyone run into this problem?
It is worth clarifying that this **only happens in Android**, in IOS it adapts, it would seem to work and **LottieFullScreen = true**, because it adapts to the height of the device, regardless of the device.

thank you very much to all.